# Why isn't my azurewebsites.net is still accessible after connecting to a virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

So I have setup a web app, virtual network, application gateway using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app#configure-a-web-application-behind-a-new-application-gateway). I also added a virtual network gateway to the vnet so that I can integrate my web app to the vnet.

Now correct me if I am wrong but isn't the purpose of integrating your web app with virtual network to make it more secure? if so then I should only be able to access my web app through the application gateway public IP correct?

Currently when I hit the the myapp.azurewebsites.net, I get to the application.

Do I have to do something extra here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing several different things here.

Application gateway is just a proxy (more or less). It has no control over whatever server it is routing traffic to. It cannot magically make it not accept traffic not from application gateway. That is for the server to decide (in your case you need to use web.config as far as I remember to restrict incoming IP addresses only to the IP addresses of the application gateway). So adding application gateway to the mix doesnt make it more or less secure.

Vnet integration works only one way, FROM the webapp inside the Vnet. Things inside the vnet cannot talk back to the webapp using "internal" vnet traffic, they have to use external IP address. So this wont really help you.

If you want your webapp to be available only inside the VNet your best bet is App Service Environment, but its a lot more expensive :(

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. So my goal is to protect my web app against DDoS and bunch of other threats like SQL injection. I believe to do that I need an Application Gateway(AG). Meaning I can add/enable those features on AG. So in that case I won't need a Virtual Network Gateway(VNG) and also do not need to integrate my Webapp with Virtual Network. All I have to have is a Virtual Network(VN) and an AG. The AG sends the traffic to Webapp. Then use my Webapp's web.config to blacklist all IPs and whitelist the traffic that comes from VN. Do you agree?

Comment: yes, you need WAF application gateway + whitelist its external ip address (most likely) as it will try to reach your webapp via "internet", not internally